# How can I run a .exe file from a windows service using c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, exe

I'm new to the windows services and visual studio. I am trying to start a .exe file from a wind32 application. The code works fine and there is no error. I am using a CreateProcess() method and checked whether the method is running properly. There is no issues in it. The .exe file which i am calling simply creates text document. When i call that .exe file from console, it works fine, it creates the file. But when I call it from the wind32 app, it does not create any file. I am using Visual studio 2019. This is my code for calling the .exe file. `

```
STARTUPINFO info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
info.cb = sizeof(info);
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

LPCWSTR path = L"C:\\HP\\...(pathofexe).exe";
bool bSuccess = CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);

if (bSuccess)
{
    cout << "Success";
}
else
{
    cout << "Error : " << GetLastError() << endl;
}`
```

Comment: At a guess the user the service is running as doesn't have permission to access all the required files

Comment: The file may just not be where you would expect it, because the new process working directory will be that of the application that called it. As a side note, you have to close those two handles returned into `LPPROCESS_INFORMATION` yourself, with `CloseHandle`

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: @Rapunzel Who was that for? (use tags)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes For you

Comment: @Rapunzel About the working directory, or the handle closing?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes About the working directory

Comment: @Rapunzel Alright.. I'll format it as an answer, it may get a bit long.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Okie

Answer (score 0):

Rgarding the working directory mismatch that was discussed in the comments, The file may not be there because it's simply somewhere else.

You call:

```
CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
```

Assuming you've read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), you know the 8th parameter specifies the directory where the new process will run. Because you use `NULL`, this directory will be the same as that of the caller process, I assume `"C:\\Users\\HP\\source\\repos\\ThisThingsName\\Debug\\"`.

That alone is not a problem, but given the context I believe the *callee* (`SampleService.exe`) calls the file function from its relative path, `"\\Success.txt"`, rather than the full path,  is that right?

In that case, when you open `SampleService.exe` manually, `Success.txt` would appear in `"C:\\Users\\HP\\source\\repos\\SampleService\\Debug\\"`. However, when you open it using `CreateProcess`, it runs in `"C:\\Users\\HP\\source\\repos\\ThisThingsName\\Debug\\"` (because you did not specify otherwise), which is also where `Success.txt` would appear.

As I type this, I'm starting to doubt it, actually. Haven't you checked where it appears in Explorer?

Comment: Regarding the caller process, yes, it is in the same directory of that of callee(which is "C:\\Users\\HP\\source\\repos\\Tests\\x64\\Debug\\Tests.exe). Success.txt is simply a file to check whether the CreateProcess() works properly.(as it is the wind32 application, I created to check it). The problem is when I run this same code as a console application, it runs properly. But as a windows service application, it is not calling Tests.exe

Comment: @Rapunzel Not calling? Does `CreateProcess` return false, or...?

Comment: It returns true and Success.txt got created. But, the Test.exe is not called. As i mentioned earlier, Tests.exe creates a text file( with the list of running windows services). But the file that was supposed to create by Tests.exe is not created.

Comment: @Rapunzel Oh... That's an entirely different structure than I anticipated... So there are two files in question. Do you have access to the code of Tests, or a way to know what is going on inside?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to run Tests.exe file from SampleService(wind32 application). But, the method CreateProcess() runs just fine, but Tests.exe is not. Is there any different way for calling an .exe file from windows service.

Comment: @Rapunzel I understand that, but is Tests yours (and do you have its code), or a third-party thing? You can call an application using [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/), but that's deprecated, you can use it for debugging purposes though.

Comment: @Rapunzel Is Tests a console app? Then you could try to debug it by printing at each significant step. Or, if it doesn't run at all, did you check the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` returned by `CreateProcess`? What is in there?

Comment: Tests is not a console app. How can I check the PROCESS_INFORMATION? can u please send the code ?

Comment: @Rapunzel I don't have a code sample for this, but I'll try to explain. `CreateProcess` returns several handles/identifiers to the newly created process into its last parameter. In the sample you provided, it's the `processInfo` variable that will contain this after the function returns. Theoretically speaking, if the process actually didn't get launched, they should be zero. If they are nonzero, that means the process is there, just not doing what it should. Knowing which of these two cases you're dealing with should help you with debugging.

Comment: @Rapunzel I am glad you have got your solution, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.